# Problema con CanDeactivate Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic, angular7, ionic4

¿Alguien le ha funcionado el CanDeactivate en Ionic 4? Lo he intentado usar y nunca puedo leer las propiedades o metodos del componente al cual estoy enlazando, siempre me retorna un null.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginFormComponent } from '../login-form/login-form.component';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CanExitGuard implements CanDeactivate<LoginFormComponent> {

  canDeactivate(component:LoginFormComponent, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
  {

    console.log(component);
    return component.canDeactivate();

  }
}
```

agregué el guard en el router

```
canDeactivate:[CanExitGuard]
```

y tambien agregué el guard en los providers de **app.module.ts**.

Básicamente la función CanDeactivate del Guard se ejecuta perfectamente lo que no puedo es tener acceso al compomente que estoy enlazando al Guard.

Necesito que el ese Guard chequee si en el formulario hay datos que no se hayan guardado antes que el usuario salga de la pantalla, si hay datos no guardado se le pregunta al usuario si está seguro que desea salir y perder la información no guardada.

Abajo pongo un ejemplo básico de lo que estoy tratando de hacer.
Gracias si alguien puede ayudar!!!

Answer (score 0):

En este [tutorial](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-navigation-and-routing-ultimate-guide) aparece como hacerlo. Básicamente debes incorporar la propiedad `canDeactivate` en en el `.module.ts` del LoginForm component, no del `app-routing.module.ts`.